# using getElementsByClassName in for_loop does not work proprly

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, foreach, getelementsbyclassname

I have a @foreach loop in my laravel code, in each iteration it shows a table. I want to make a button to show or hide table for each one. I'm using  getElementsByClassName to change ID of table tag for each table of iteration, but it works just for first table. Here is my code:

```
<script>
    var cc = -3;
</script>
    @foreach($last as $t)

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                cc = cc +1;
                document.getElementsByClassName("table")[cc].setAttribute("id",cc);
                $("#hide").click(function(){
                    $("#"+cc).hide();
                });
                $("#show").click(function(){
                    $("#"+cc).show();
                });
            });
        </script>

        <p>If you click on the "Hide" button, table will desapear.</p>

        <button id ="hide">Hide</button>
            <button id ="show">Show</button>

<table class="table">
......
```

I found -3 for cc first value by chance. I have know Idea why it is not working. I'm working on it for 2 days but it doesn't work. 
Any Idea?

Comment: You are mixing backend and frontend code

Comment: You cant have numbers as IDs. If at all the foreach should be in JS. But it seems you are better off with a better selector. Would need real code (fiddle) to see more.

Comment: in which part? @William

Comment: Isn’t that a foreach on the backend side? You need to keep it all on the same side

Comment: @AdamP I think that is class, for Id I can which it works for first one.

Comment: @William I'm using laravel and I need a for_loop in my blade so I used foreach. I don't think, it is the problem. it should be something about how  getElementsByClassName works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a solution that doesn't require a loop on `<script>`.

```
@foreach($last as $t)

    <p>If you click on the "Hide" button, table will desapear.</p>

    <button class="hide-button">Hide</button>
    <button class="show-button">Show</button>

    <table class="table">
......
<script>
    $(".hide-button").click(function(){
        $(this).next().next().hide();
    });
    $(".show-button").click(function(){
        $(this).next().show();
    });
</script>
```

it would have been easier to target the right table if the buttons were grouped in with the table in a `<div>` (for example)

```
@foreach($last as $t)

    <p>If you click on the "Hide" button, table will desapear.</p>
    <div>
        <button class="hide-button">Hide</button>
        <button class="show-button">Show</button>

        <table class="table">
    ......
    </div>
@endforeach
<script>
    $(".hide-button").click(function(){
        $(this).parent('div').find('table.table').hide();
    });
    $(".show-button").click(function(){
        $(this).parent('div').find('table.table').show();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it didn't show the "hide" button so I changed ` "class = hide"` and `"class = show"` to `"id = hide" `and `"id = show"` so it show both buttons but now they didn't work even for first table.

Comment: I wrote <script> after foreach, and now it just work for first table. (same as my first code) @N69S

Comment: @afsane i edited my answer. corrected the wrong selectors. and you should not use the same `id` on multiple DOMs

Comment: this time again when I write the script before foreach, it does not work at all, but when I bring it inside foreach, this time it is work for tables except the last one. (for example if foreach iterate 3 times, 2first tables work fine but for the third one it doesn't)

Comment: @afsane put the `<script>` after the `@foreach`